# Windows could not start the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service on local computer. Error 1053

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running Windows 7 32 bit and I have IIS, Visual Studio 2008, 2010 installed. I am haunted by this error in SQL Server 2008 which is:

> Windows could not start the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service on local computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

I have Googled and visited many other sites.

I have tried following:

- changed Account permission to Local System Account and no luck.
- uninstalled and re-installed: no luck.
- checked the port in Client Protocols and it is set 1433.
- added Network Service account to the Microsoft SQL Server folder in program files.

I cant check the log file because it doesn't exist in the LOG folder of MS SQL folder.
I have changed registry information from fix articles about this issue but no luck from those sites.

It is really annoying because i installed SQL Server 2005 Express earlier and I got the same error message so that's why I uninstalled this and decided to give SQL Server 2008 Express a go and I receive the same error.

This is really slowing me down because I have developed a lot of the web pages in my website and now I want to add functionality to the site and I need SQL Server and this has really stopped me from working.

Can someone help please? I really need to get this fixed i have tried everything that the sites provide in Google. If you require more information ill be glad to give you the feedback to get this solved as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

great news. i managed to install SQL Server 2008 Express at last. What i did was i downloaded Windows Install Cleanup.

1. But first i uninstalled everything that relates to SQL Server 2008 from controlpanel>programs>programs and features including the sql server vss writer, sql server browser.
2. Then i deleted the folders from regedit.exe and these folders were the sql server folders in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINBE/software/microsoft/microsoft sql server,basically all the folders that start with microsoft sql server "xxxx".
3. I also deleted the Microsoft sql server directory from Hkey_current_user/software/microsoft/microsoft sql server.
4. Then i deleted the microsoft sql server directory from my program files on the system. once all these directories were removed from regedit and my pc,
5. I then finally used Windows install cleanup and removed anything that related to microsoft sql server 2008 and thats it.
6. I then installed sql server 2008 Express sucessfully. thanks for all the people who took the time to view my issue and thanks for those who gave me the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Open the event viewer and dig through the logs:
Open Windows Explorer and go to

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools

Open Event Viewer

Expand Windows Logs

Look in Application, Security, and System for errors.

Comment: Or just type "eventvwr.msc" in Run... (shortcut [Windows]+[R]). When you get the actual error message, post it here.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying lads, appreciate it. Error which is: "Faulting application name: sqlservr.exe, version: 2009.100.1600.1, time stamp: 0x4bb6b04d
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16559, time stamp: 0x4ba9b21e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00028ee9
Faulting process id: 0xf98
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb9d87a3acc595
Faulting application path: c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: e1b711dd-097a-11e0-abd4-0019db8c7944". Thanks

Comment: Also the event viewer gave me this log which was not an error but information - MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS "The Service Broker protocol transport is disabled or not configured."

Comment: Also i before sql server 2008 r2 stopped working i bought and installed spyware doctor, could this be the reason sql server 2008 r2 isnt working?

Comment: Could be. I don't believe that blocking port 1433 will prevent the service from starting, but it would cause network access issues. This post shows that you aren't the only one who's having these troubles with Spyware doctor:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/2f3cfd1f-7ac9-42d2-8f50-cec58bcc9aae

Comment: Hi, great news. i managed to install SQL Server 2008 r2 at last. What i did was i downloaded Windows Install Cleanup. But first i uninstalled everything that relates to SQL Server 2008 from controlpanel>programs>programs and features including the sql server vss writer, sql server browser. then i deleted the folders from regedit.exe and these folders were the sql server folders in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINBE/software/microsoft/microsoft sql server,basically all the folders that start with microsoft sql server "xxxx". follow on.......

Comment: I also deleted the Microsoft sql server directory from Hkey_current_user/software/microsoft/microsoft sql server. Then i deleted the microsoft sql server directory from my program files on the system. once all these directories were removed from regedit and my pc, i then finally used Windows install cleanup and removed anything that related to microsoft sql server 2008 r2 and thats it. i then installed sql server 2008 r2 sucessfully. thanks for all the people who took the time to view my issue and thanks for those who gave me the feedback.